# Basic Loop through a matrix with pasting column names into result objects

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (samples x species) which I want to loop this command through (column-wise):

```
dist <- vegdist(decostand(X,"standardize",MARGIN=2), method="euclidean")
```

I need the name of the column in each of the new dist-values. So if my columns are called A, B, C, then the result should be dist-values called Dist.A, Dist.B, Dist.C, and so on. I believe this can be done with paste, but I have no clue how.

Comment: Do you have a `data.frame` or `matrix` as it is confusing?  Also, it is better to provide the name of `library` which has `vegdist` or `deconstand` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try (if it is a `data.frame`)

```
 d1[] <- lapply(colnames(d1), function(x) paste(d1[,x], x, sep="."))
```

Or

```
 d1[] <- Map(function(x,y) paste(x, y, sep="."), d1, colnames(d1))
```

If it is a `matrix`

```
  m1[] <- paste(m1, colnames(m1)[col(m1)],sep=".")
```

#### data

```
 m1 <- matrix(1:15, ncol=3, dimnames=list(NULL, LETTERS[1:3]))
 d1 <- as.data.frame(m1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but i am getting a matrix/df with values with added column names. Here i tried to explain it better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159529/basic-loop-through-a-matrix-with-pasting-column-names-into-result-objects-pt-ii

Comment: @nouse I showed the solution for both cases.  DOn't know what your expected result is.